# Adding an Identifier in Google CloudVision request API for tracking purposes

Tags: google-cloud-vision

While using google cloudVision services we have a need to track individual requests made and the response. Is there a way I can generate an ID as a memo field to every request I make to the CloudVision API & read it in the usage logs/ billing statement?

I can get close to this with timestamps- but with concurrent usages and latencies, mapping can get challenging. Along with reconciliation, this will also help track error codes and reasons

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering whether you can log every request which has error yourself?

You may sending request in parallel in multiple thread, but in each thread you can just write the request and its result to a GCS bucket to record the log.

Comment: My need is to be able to match every request with payment details from google. This is to meet reconciliation needs from Audit. Is there a way google and reflect a memofield in their usage summary

Comment: I see. But I think you can still log every request to a GCS folder. Then perform reconciliation by analyzing your own logs. I believe right now there is no way but what you said is a interesting feature to consider.